# Is there any way to close/remove tabs in pysimplegui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pysimplegui

I have a program, and I need to open & close tabs, I have the opening part, but I can't figure out the closing part. I know I could probably just make the tabs invisible, but that would still take up some RAM, am I correct? I have looked through the tab section in the cookbook, but I can't find anything. Am I missing something, or is this just not doable, my project is quite large, but if you need some code, I can provide.

Comment: No method provided to remove element from existing layout. Of course, it can be done by tkinter code, but you have to know the detail about how a element configured in PySimpleGUI.

Comment: Making the tab not visible is the way to close/remove a tab.  It was designed this way so that tabs can be re-opened if desired.  Feel free to open an enhancement on the PySimpleGUI GitHub if one isn't present for deletion.  The psgtest application uses tabs with a right click to close if an example is desired.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project where I am trying to do the same thing and I think I have a way that works thanks to Jason's comment. I've pasted below the code I used for a button with key='-del-' that I added into my event loop.

```
if event == '-del-':
        #get the index of the tab that is selected
        index = window["-tabs-"].TKNotebook.index('current')
        
        #remove the selected tab from the TabGroup.TKNotebook
        #TabGroup.TkNotebook is part of the structure for how a TabGroup is defined
        window["-tabs-"].TKNotebook.forget(window["-tabs-"].TKNotebook.select())
        #Remove the tab_element from the list of tabs (TabGroup.Rows)
        window["-tabs-"].Rows.pop(index)
        #Update the TabCount(part of the structure of TabGroups)
        window["-tabs-"].TabCount -= 1

        window.refresh
```

I recommend checking out the master code in the PySimpleGUI.py file which is how a TabGroup is defined. A more elegant way to do this would be to add, for example, a delete_tab method into the TabGroup Class that is defined. I will probably end up doing this myself eventually but still playing around with it to make sure I am not forgetting to update any other parts of the structure.