# Is there a way to delete tabs in pythonsimpleGUI?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pysimplegui

Have a project where I am trying to be able to add and delete tabs in python simple GUI. Figured out how to add tabs using the .add_tab() method for a TabGroup, but I haven't figure out how to delete tabs from a TabGroup.

Ran across this post: [Is there any way to close/remove tabs in pysimplegui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73395665/is-there-any-way-to-close-remove-tabs-in-pysimplegui) which makes it seem like the method does not exist. Wondering how to use the backdoor route of using direct tkinter to modify pysimple gui tabs